# python 2.7 add '\' to a string

Tags: python, string

```
  a = hex(1)
  b = a[1] + a[0] + a[2]
```

I am trying to turn my hex to the hex with \ bracket in it since those work with sockets.

a = hex(1) is 0x1 in hex and \x01 is what I need. So what I did is

```
b = a[1] + a[0] + a[2]
```

which turns it into x01 as I would want. However I cant added the '\' in python

```
b = '\' + a[1] + a[0] + a[2]
```

gives me an error

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @Sherzod A somewhat obvious syntax error…

Comment: The solution is `'\\'`. However, even with that, I'm not sure what you're doing is really accomplishing whatever it is you want…

Comment: For a client program I have \x01 works 0x1 doesn't and regular 1 doesn't either.

Comment: You probably want a specific *byte* then. Concatenating backslashes to strings is not how you get that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you don't want a literal backslash followed by `x01`, but the character `\x01`:

```
>>> a = hex(1)
>>> b = chr(int(a[2:], 16))
>>> b
'\x01'
```

`int` parses the string "1" as a base-16 number, and `chr` converts the resulting number into a character with that codepoint.

Note that the result *does not* contain any backslashes, and is instead a length-one string, with `\x01` being merely a representation of the "Start of Heading" control character, also known as <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd>.

```
>>> len('\x01')
1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
b = '\\' + a[1] + a[0] + a[2]
print(b)
```

Comment: \\x01 is not what I want

Comment: Try printing it @bob!

Comment: My mistake, I don't want the literal blackslash. Rather print(repr(b))

Answer (score 1):

`'\'` is a special character in python, the "escape character". For example `'\n'` represents a newline and `'\t'` a tab. You can also "escape" the escape character by using a double backslash. So `'\\'` will print a single backslash.

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> print("\{number}".format(number=hex(1)))
\0x1
```